How to rewrite the url using .htaccess file?
I designed a website where I am fetching data from database and I want to create a user friendly url dynamically using .htaccess file. My url type is like
https://example.com/lrc.php?ti=Down+Bad&ar=Taylor+Swift&no=151107

and I want my url to be
https://example.com/down-bad-lyrics-download-taylor-swift-151107` I am using this 

I used
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)-lyrics-download-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)-([0-9]+)$ lrc.php?ti=$1&ar=$2&no=$3 [L]

but it is not working.

And "it is not working" means what, exactly ?

it is giving 404 when using

And is that 404 returned by the http server or by your application logic?

Apart from getting that directive to get applied in general (there are many tutorials explaining that) you will face the non trivial issue that you have to replace the dashes ("-") inside the captured parts into blanks or plus signs and you will have to capitalize words, again a non trivial task.

If the situation you have (that you describe in the question) really cannot be changed (upper versus lower case letters, dashes versus plus signs or blanks) I would suggest that you simply capture all of the slug and hand it over to your application logic where you can then easily process it by means of whatever framework you are using there.

thanks I have made it

That is great, congratulations. SO now you want to either post your solution as an answer for others here or you want to delete this question.

If you don't need to replace the - characters with +, this regex will reformat to the other URL structure:
input: down-bad-lyrics-download-taylor-swift-151107
rgx: /^((?:\-?\w+)+)\-lyrics\-download\-((?:\-?\w+)+)-(\d+)$/
output: lrc.php?ti=down-bad&ar=taylor-swift&no=151107
Explanation

((?:\-?\w+)+?) - capture the song title as a repeating sequence of letters or numbers, each led by an optional hyphen
\-lyrics\-download\- - match but don't capture this sequence that shows up in the middle
((?:\-?\w+)+?) - capture the artist as a second repeating sequence of letters or numbers, each led by an optional hyphen
- - match but don't capture the last hyphen
(\d+)$ - capture a series of digits immediately preceding the end of the string as the number

